# Is it possible to return a value from a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, return

Here is a pen to what I am building https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/GmrgVL?editors=0010

I am trying to return values from each option clicked from the dropdowns so I can add all of them up on the last box but I have no clue how to access them outside of the click function and if that is even possible. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
var val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text()

$("#dropdown1 ul li").click(function(){
$("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
$("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());


val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text();

})
```

Comment: it depends on what exactly you mean by "return"... because, no, you can't return from an asynchronous callback to the outer function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop You can update variables that were defined in the outer function, but that may not have the effect you desire.

Comment: How do I that exactly? because I've tried alerting the variable I set inside the function (val1) outside the function but the global variable remains the same

Comment: does the alert not happen long before the click? that's the undesireable effect i was alluding to.The variable's value does get updated, but that won't affect things that used the value of the variable before it was updated.

Comment: the alert happens before the click and it displays "1" because it is what I set val1 to prior to the click event, i tried updating box 6's text with this code $("box6 p:first-child").text(val1) outside of the click function and after the click event happens but it still displays "1", i know it's possible to update box 6's text to val1 by declaring it inside the function but this disallows me to add it up to the other options "clicked" on the other dropdowns/functions

Answer (score 0):

The code you include within your post should work. Everytime dropdown1 is clicked, val1 should be changed. However, in the pen you linked to, you have:

```js
  $("#dropdown1 ul li").click(function(){
    $("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());
    
    var val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text();
    
    //...
   
   }
```

The `var` before `val1` makes all the difference. Without `var`, that line sets the value of val1 in the *global* namespace. But with `var`, that line creates a new variable within the *function* namespace; after the click handler function exits, that local val1 is destroyed without being used, and then it's re-created on the next click. But without `var`, you'll always be updating `val1` in the global namespace, which is what you want. Does this accomplish what you need?

Comment: I tried updating box6's text with the new val1 value with the added var before the val1 with $("#box6 p:first-child).text(val1) after the click but it still displays the value I set it to on the global scope

Comment: You *do not* want the "var". If it still doesn't work without the "var," then there must be some issue other than the one I described above.

Answer (score 0):

You meant something like this?:

```js
var val1;

$("#dropdown1 ul li").click(function(){
$("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
$("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());


val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text();

});
```

So every time you click on element that you need, it will store in `GLOBAL`(it's important) variable, so you can use it's value everywhere you want. And in your pen, I noticed that you have some problems with semicolons.